# Detox UI tests run erroneously on CircleCI 2.0

Tags: react-native, circleci, detox, circleci-2.0

We are building react-native app (iOS only) and for e2e testing we use Detox (https://github.com/wix/detox). When I run these tests locally everything works fine but I'm unable to make them run in CircleCI (2.0).

Here is what our config.yml file looks like (in .circleci folder)

- https://ibb.co/eJc0pc
- https://ibb.co/jA3JaH

And these are the relevant package.json parts

under scripts:

- https://ibb.co/fq1RUc

and then:

- https://ibb.co/bXRMvH

When I run these tests on CircleCI everything works up to the test phase.  There it behaves erroneously. First it finds the booted device but it seems like detox skips some of the setup steps it does when run locally and tries to run some test steps but these seems to be chosen randomly and are not even part of the same test function.

- https://ibb.co/ksHfNx
- https://ibb.co/cXcrUc

Did anyone encounter similar problems?

Comment: Run your tests with `--loglevel verbose --debug-synchronization` for the full log. I suspect your app is never idle in CI, therefore the action/expectation is never invoked.

Comment: Those screenshots were already with verbose logs. I added --debug-synchronization 1000 but the result looks exactly the same and actually I don't even see any sync logs. Detox launch seems to end on step 2 whereas locally it performs more steps. To the second part of your message I experienced app hanging on expectation/action because it had some background communication locally before but it looked differently. The setup process finished and then detox just time outed. This doesn't happen. Screenshots with sync logs: https://ibb.co/jeCMvH 
https://ibb.co/dN4ZFH

Comment: What about the test itself, how does it look?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It should run ±15 test suites and each of these suites consists of approximately from 20-40 tests. Do you want me to post part of these tests? I can do that but I repeat that these tests work as expected locally.

Comment: For info only: [Cross-posted to the CircleCI forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/wix-detox-ui-tests-dont-run-on-circleci/20920).

Comment: As indicated on the other link, this question contains a number of JSON and config artefacts that would be best supplied as text in the question itself. When you get a moment, would you edit the question? Thanks!

Comment: I will do so halfer, I'm currently working on different part of the project and UI tests are not of the highest priority now so it won't be immediately.